# 'Alias is never used' PHPStorm error message within my PHP file

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm, autoload, psr-0

I am following the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/alecsammon/php-raml-parser) to install PHP RAML Parser

I run `composer install` and created the `index.php` below but it isn't working, I get an error:

> Class 'Raml\ParseConfiguration' not found in /cygdrive/c/src/myapp/Raml/Parser.php on line 83

When I hover over the line `use \Raml\Parser` I get the PHPStorm warning message (Alias never used)

My `index.php`:

```
<?php
require ('Raml/Parser.php');
use \Raml\Parser; // Alias \Raml\Parser is never used
$parser = new \Raml\Parser();
```

Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong?

Comment: You have `use \Raml\Parser;` but then you specifying FQN when creating the class instance -- in such case `use` line is not needed indeed. Try with `$parser = new Parser();` instead.

Comment: Also -- I want to point out that the "class not found" issue has nothing to do with the warning that PhpStorm gives you -- those are separate issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the file `Raml/Parser.php` contains:

```
namespace Raml;

class Parser {}
```

You can either do this:

```
require ('Raml/Parser.php');
$parser = new \Raml\Parser();
```

or this:

```
require ('Raml/Parser.php');
use \Raml\Parser;
$parser = new Parser();
```

`use` imports a class/interface/trait into your current namespace and allows to use a shorter name instead of the fully qualified, backspaced name. It also allows to switch to a different class by only changing the `use` statement, and not every name reference in the whole class, but this benefit is very small because using PHPStorm brings some powerful renaming abilities itself.

Comment: silly me forget the autoloader file but this got me on the right track